# Adding functions within a string

Tags: python

I want to add a specific time delay within a string using time.sleep() , I am building a Text Interactive Game, I've tried this:

```
print(f"**inner thoughts** hmmmmm... {time.sleep(2)} maybe big nuke? {time.sleep(2)} or AK 47s for everyone? {time.sleep(2)} or kill him with our kindness? {time.sleep(2)} ")
```

The problem is that I get (None) instead of a time delay when I execute the code.

> **inner thoughts** hmmmmm... None maybe big nuke? None or AK 47s for everyone? None or kill him with our kindness? None

Comment: An interesting attempt, but I don't think that works, as the f-string is evaluated as a whole first. Maybe you can use `print(..., end='')` many times, between which you insert `time.sleep(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f-strings are built all at once; you won't see this printed piecemeal with delays, because the string isn't finished when you `sleep`, so `print` hasn't even been called yet. If you want to do this, you have to make separate `print` calls, with `sleep`s in between; there is no benefit to embedding it in the f-string, and you'd want to do something like this to actually print each component before waiting:

```
print("**inner thoughts** hmmmmm... ", end="", flush=True)
time.sleep(2)
print(" maybe big nuke? ", end="", flush=True)
time.sleep(2)
print(" or AK 47s for everyone? ", end="", flush=True)
time.sleep(2)
print(" or kill him with our kindness? ", end="", flush=True)
time.sleep(2)
print(" ")
```

The `end=""` ensures you don't move to a new line (following your original all-in-one string's format), while `flush=True` ensures the data is not stuck waiting in a buffer while you're sleeping (without it, the likely behavior would be an eight second wait, followed by all the text appearing at once as the newline from the final `print` cause line-buffering to dump the buffer).

Comment: Note: I kept the exact spacing of your f-string, even down to leading and trailing whitespace that looks a little odd to me; drop whatever isn't actually needed at your leisure.

Comment: thx master :) it was really helpful , I spent alot of time on courses , seems to me they don't teach that much , would you please recommend me a better way to learn python?

Comment: @gamesmemer: Run through tutorials, and practice. Find dumb online challenges (Project Euler, Hackerrank, whatever), and solve them all in Python. When you use a function, read the docs at least once, even if you think you know it. Work interactively in `ipython` so you can just do `func?` or `obj.method?` and see the docs easily. When you come up with solutions that feel kludgy, start researching better ways to do them (hint: When it comes to brute force attacks on silly problems, the `itertools` &`collections` modules are a godsend; for math, `math` & `statistics`), then rewrite it.

Comment: Eventually, when you're good enough, try to teach someone else the basics of Python. There is nothing that helps you grasp a subject better than having to teach it to someone else. And there is nothing that helps you develop an intuition for code smell that's better than correcting a newbie's attempt to solve an exercise.

Comment: thx man you are really inspiring me , I will sure teach beginners when I become better in python , thx again :) I will follow you for more knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I provide template approaches to this question.

Version 1, use flag to cut the text (`|` for this sample):

```py
text = "**inner thoughts** hmmmmm... | maybe big nuke? | or AK 47s for everyone? | or kill him with our kindness? |"
array = text.split("|")
for s in array:
    print(s, end="")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Version 2: custom delay time

```py
import time
import re

text = "**inner thoughts** hmmmmm... {2} maybe big nuke? {2} or AK 47s for everyone? {1} or kill him with our kindness? {2}"
sub_text_array = re.split(r"{\d+}", text)
delay_array = [0] + [int(s) for s in re.findall(r"{(\d+)}", text)]
for index in range(len(sub_text_array)):
    time.sleep(delay_array[index])
    print(sub_text_array[index], end="")
```